# Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-ADDS - Error Install

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016

So I get the follow error only on installed RSAT-ADDS:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-ADDS
Install-WindowsFeature : The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The referenced assembly could not be found. Error: 0x80073701
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-ADDS
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature],
    Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DISMAPI_Error__Failed_To_Enable_Updates,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWind
   owsFeatureCommand

Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
False   No             Failed         {}
```

Same error if use Server Manager.
os: Windows Server 2016